# Import from csv to ms access tables

Tags: vba, ms-access

Can some provide me a VBA macro to import data from a CSV file into ms access tables ?

Comment: VBA and macro are contradictory.  Which is it?

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO tblSomeTable ( [TRADE DATE], REP, REPID, [ACCOUNT/POLICY],
                          CUSTOMER, [REP# COMPANY], [PRODUCT NAME], QUANTITY, [FACE AMOUNT],
                          [GROSS COMMISSION], [CUSTOMER SSN] )
SELECT [TRADE DATE], REP, REPID, [ACCOUNT/POLICY],
        CUSTOMER, [REP# COMPANY], [PRODUCT NAME], QUANTITY, [FACE AMOUNT],
        [GROSS COMMISSION], [CUSTOMER SSN]
FROM [Text;
      FMT=Delimited;
      HDR=YES;
      CharacterSet=437;
      DATABASE=C:\Documents And Settings\spauldb\Desktop].Transactions_Jan1_to_Jan30.csv
WHERE [TRADE DATE] Is Not Null;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use TransferText for CSV:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "NewTable2", "c:\docs\ltd.csv", True
```

It is often a good idea, but not always necessary, to use an import specification or to import to an existing table when working with text files.

Comment: Hi Remou, long time no see. Well I am using CharacterSet=437 to insert csv to avoid truncating memo text fields, like how @SmartestVEGA showed it. However due to the character limit some of the chars are missing. E.g. " turns into either ô or ö etc Do you suggest anyway to incorporate UTF8?

Comment: All it took wz replacing 437 with 950 for UTF8 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

See if [Docmd.TransferSpreadSheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220766(office.11).aspx) helps.